# Conjunction and disjunction for google place api keyword parameter

Tags: google-places-api

I want to pass disjunction of conjunctions in keyword parameter.
For example:

keyword=pizza AND hrs OR pizza AND family

I'm executing the following request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=41.141,-73.2631&radius=25000&types=restaurant&keyword=pizza+hrs|pizza+family&sensor=false

I'm not sure whether

keyword=pizza+hrs|pizza+family

is equivalient logicaly to the following expression.

keyword=(pizza AND hrs) OR (pizza AND family)

Any ideas is it true?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Places API does not support disjunctions or conjunctions in the keyword parameter. Please feel free to request this feature in our issue tracker: [Places API Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request)

Thanks!

Comment: In that case, how do we cope with worldwide apps? Do I have to translate my keyword according to the current country language?